# Prove $\lfloor na\rfloor=\lfloor(n+1)a\rfloor$ for some $n$.

Tags: calculus, analysis

Prove that for any $0<a<1$, there exists  $n \in \mathbb Z_{>0}$ such that $\lfloor na\rfloor=\lfloor(n+1)a\rfloor$ where $\lfloor*\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Please derive it from the definition of the floor function.

Comment: As it stands you can just take $n=0$, no?

Comment: My guess is that you meant it for *every* $a$, not just for *some* $a$.

Comment: Sorry I've edited.

Comment: Is this the exact wording of the question? It does seem sloppy.

Comment: No it's just a part of a question that I needed to prove something else

Comment: Okay, well, it is bad to include "$0\leq a<1$" after the "for some" phrase, because it is easily misread as wanting $n$ that works with all $a$, rather than $n$ depending on $a$. You want: "For all $0\leq a<1$ there is some $n$ such that..."

Comment: OK I've changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Find $n$ so that $1-\frac{1}{n}\leq a<1-\frac{1}{n+1}$